# Yii2 - hasOne with leftJoin

Tags: yii, yii2

I am trying to add **leftJoin** to the **hasOne** method, but it seems that it is not working. Data from the main table is there, but not from the joined table. Code:

```
public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserKeys::classname(), ['id' => 'userKey_id'])
            ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id = userKeys.user_id');
    }
```

Comment: How do you call the relation?

Answer (score 1):

You should use **[viaTable](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#junction-table)** instead of **leftJoin**

```
public function getUser(){
    return $this->hasOne(UserKeys::classname(), ['id' => 'userKey_id'])
    ->viaTable('users', ['id'=>'user_id']);
}
```